# Travelling to Taipei (Taiwan) with expired Japan Single Entry Tourist Visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, taiwan

**I am planning to travel to Taipei on the basis of expired Japan Tourist Visa**. I visited Japan **2 years back** and have that visa stamp in my passport. **That single entry visa is now expired**.

**My Nationality:** Indian with Indian passport

**Please confirm if I can visit Taipei (Taiwan) after getting TAC on the basis of my expired Japan single entry visa.** 
Has anyone ever traveled to Taiwan on the basis of their expired US,UK,Canada, Australia, NZ, Japan, or South Korean visa.

As per new Visa-Exempt law for certain nationalities as mentioned in following Taiwan immigration website and **Travel Authorization Certificate (TAC)** website, we can use expired Japan visa to apply for TAC:

a) https://www.roc-taiwan.org/ausyd_en/post/60.html

b) https://niaspeedy.immigration.gov.tw/nia_southeast/languageAction  (TAC Application website)

Comment: I am planning to visit next week. So, please help me in deciding whether I can take this route to visit Taipei/Taiwan.

Comment: The exemption you describe only applies to certain nationalities but you haven't listed yours.

Comment: I am an Indian with Indian passport. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Since your Japanese visa is expired by less than 10 years, you can use it and the TAC to visit Taiwan

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines (if check-in staff tries to deny you boarding, point to this):

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of India with a printed
>   Travel Authorization Certificate for a maximum stay of 14
>   days. The Travel Authorization Certificate is obtained at
>   https://oa1.immigration.gov.tw/nia_southeast/. They must also
>   have a valid resident or **visitor visa** (incl. electronic)
>   issued by Australia, Canada, Ireland (Rep.), **Japan**, Korea
>   (Rep.), New Zealand, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member
>   State. A resident card or **visa that has expired
>   less than 10 years prior to the date of arrival can still be
>   used for entry.** Passengers with a work permit are not
>   eligible.